# How to display reply of the GET message on the broswer?

Tags: python, proxy, http-caching

I got the assignment where I was needed to write a server program, more like a proxy server, where I send a GET request from the browser while running the proxy server.  It should check it in the cache whether it exist or not then send back the reply (html documents) otherwise it ask the server the requested page and return it to the proxy server where it would be directed back to the client (browser).

I have done a awful lot of google search to find hints but haven't found one.  If anyone can point me to the right direction or give some hint, I would be grateful.

Here is one example code I found but it cannot get a page and display it in the browser.

```
# import the required library
import socket, threading

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port, socket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket
        print "[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    # Entry point for thread
    def run(self):    
        print "Connection from : "+ip+":"+str(port)

        #clientsock.send("\nWelcome to the server\n\n")
        self.socket.send("\nWelcome to the server\n\n")
        data = "dummydata"

        while len(data):
            data = self.socket.recv(2048)   #clientsock.recv(2048)
            print "Client sent : "+data
            self.socket.send("You sent me : "+data)

        print "Client disconnected..."

host = "localhost"
port = 9999

# Create server socket object
tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Port reused immediately after the socket is closed
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind the server socket to the port
tcpsock.bind((host,port))
threads = []


while True:
    # Start listening to new connections
    tcpsock.listen(4)
    print "\nListening for incoming connections..."
    (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()

    # Create new thread
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock)

    # Start new thread
    newthread.start()

    threads.append(newthread)

# Wait for threads to terminate
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I very new to python and I really need help here.